# python декодирование ответа json

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, парсер, bs4

Выполняю код

```
links_product = ['https://www.wildberries.ru/catalog/10842147/detail.aspx?targetUrl=GP']
for url in links_product:
    session = requests.Session()
    response = session.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=10)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
        js_script = soup.find_all('script')
        print(str(js_script[20]))
```

Получаю ответ формата

```
<script>
    Ответ
</script>
```

Пробую декодировать json.loads(str(js_scritp[20])), но получаю ошибку

Каким образом можно получить строку ниже и работать с этими данными?

```
ssrModel: {"suppliersInfo":{"10842147":{"cod1S":10842147,"supplierName":"ВАЙЛДБЕРРИЗ ООО","ogrn":"1067746062449"}},"addToBasketEnable":true,"addToPonedEnable":true,"addToWaitingListEnable":false,"addToCreditEnable":true,"addToSellerEnable":false,"addToPreorderEnable":false,"canTakeOutInsurance":false,"deliveryInfoEnable":true,"priceForProduct":{"priceWithSale":22990,"price":27699,"sale":17,"priceDif":false},"rqCod1S":10842147,"productCard":{"link":8198421,"star":4,"brandName":"Xiaomi","brandId":29467,"brandDirectionId":0,"brandDirectionPicsCount":0,"description":"Телевизор LED Xiaomi Mi TV 4S 43 поддерживает встроенные тюнеры DVB-T, DVB-T2, DVB-C, что позволяет не подключать внешнюю приставку, чтобы смотреть цифровые телеканалы. Поддержка Smart TV, а также модуль Wi-Fi обеспечивают комфортное пользование цифровым контентом из сети. Вам будут доступны любые сведения в любом виде. Телевизор оборудован тремя разъемами HDMI и двумя разъемами USB, к которым происходит подключение внешних устройств и накопителей памяти. Xiaomi Mi TV 4S 43 поддерживает воспроизведение реалистичного изображения в разрешении 3840x2160, обладающего высокой четкостью. Картинка соответствует формату 4K, благодаря чему вы сможете погрузиться в происходящее на экране. Углы обзора 178 градусов обеспечивают получение комфортного изображения вне зависимости от ракурса просмотра. Прибор можно зафиксировать на стене, ведь он предусматривает поддержку стандарта крепления VESA 300x300.","goodsName":"Телевизор Mi TV 4S, 43\", UHD, Smart TV, Wi-Fi, DVB-T2","nomenclatures":{"10842147":{"cod1S":10842147,"artikul":"10842147","sale":17,"colorName":"серебристый","sizes":[{"characteristicId":34763855,"price":27699,"priceWithSale":22990,"quantity":1455,"sizeName":"0","dimensions":[],"storeIds":[507,116433,120762],"hasPreorder":false}],"picsCount":8,"has3DView":false,"hasVideo":true,"kit":[],"relatedGoods":[],"minOrderAmount":1,"ordersCount":11723,"regionIds":[31,33],"disableForRegion":false,"qualityRate":-1,"priceDetails":{"basicSale":17,"basicPrice":22990},"isDataLoaded":true,"productSeller":{"cod1S":10842147,"supplierName":"ВАЙЛДБЕРРИЗ ООО","ogrn":"1067746062449"},"soldOut":false}},"addedOptions":[{"property":"Версия операционной системы","subProperty":"Android TV","categoryId":7,"priority":0},{"property":"Разрешение экрана","subProperty":"3840x2160","categoryId":1,"priority":0},{"property":"Модель","subProperty":"L43M5-5ARU","categoryId":7,"priority":0},{"property":"Гарантийный срок","subProperty":"1год","categoryId":7,"priority":0},{"property":"Беспроводные интерфейсы","subProperty":"Bluetooth; Wi-Fi 802.11 b/g/n","categoryId":4,"priority":0},{"property":"Интерфейс","subProperty":"Bluetooth; Ethernet; HDMI; RJ-45; USB; Wi-Fi","categoryId":15,"priority":0},{"property":"Потребляемая мощность","subProperty":"75 Вт","categoryId":0,"priority":0},{"property":"Количество портов HDMI","subProperty":"3 шт.","categoryId":15,"priority":0},{"property":"Угол обзора","subProperty":"178 градусов","categoryId":1,"priority":0},{"property":"Частота обновления","subProperty":"60 Гц","categoryId":1,"priority":0},{"property":"Вес с упаковкой (кг)","subProperty":"9 кг","categoryId":0,"priority":0},{"property":"Вес без упаковки (кг)","subProperty":"7.26 кг","categoryId":0,"priority":0},{"property":"Высота предмета","subProperty":"21.46 см","categoryId":0,"priority":0},{"property":"Глубина предмета","subProperty":"61.3 см","categoryId":0,"priority":0},{"property":"Ширина предмета","subProperty":"96.33 см","categoryId":0,"priority":0},{"property":"Ширина упаковки","subProperty":"120 см","categoryId":0,"priority":0},{"property":"Высота упаковки","subProperty":"38 см","categoryId":0,"priority":0},{"property":"Глубина упаковки","subProperty":"80 см","categoryId":0,"priority":0},{"property":"Диагональ","subProperty":"43\"","categoryId":1,"priority":0},{"property":"Разрешение HD","subProperty":"4K HDR","categoryId":1,"priority":0},{"property":"Цифровой тюнер","subProperty":"DVB-C; DVB-T; DVB-T2","categoryId":6,"priority":0},{"property":"Формат экрана","subProperty":"16:9","categoryId":1,"priority":0},{"property":"Яркость","subProperty":"220 кд/кв.м","categoryId":1,"priority":0},{"property":"Контрастность","subProperty":"1200:1","categoryId":1,"priority":0},{"property":"Коммуникации и мультимедиа","subProperty":"Bluetooth; CI+; LAN; Smart TV; Web Браузер; Wi-Fi","categoryId":6,"priority":0},{"property":"Количество встроенных динамиков","subProperty":"2 шт.","categoryId":21,"priority":0},{"property":"Мощность акустики","subProperty":"16 Вт","categoryId":21,"priority":0},{"property":"Дополнительные разъемы","subProperty":"AV; CI+; DVB CAM; HDMI; Jack 3,5 мм; LAN; RJ-45","categoryId":15,"priority":0},{"property":"Доп. опции телевизора","subProperty":"защита от детей; телетекст; HDMI ARC; HDMI CEC","categoryId":0,"priority":0},{"property":"Размер VESA","subProperty":"300x300","categoryId":0,"priority":0},{"property":"Возможность крепления на стену","subProperty":"да","categoryId":0,"priority":0},{"property":"Skype камера","subProperty":"нет","categoryId":0,"priority":0},{"property":"Встроенный DVD","subProperty":"нет","categoryId":0,"priority":0},{"property":"Защита от детей","subProperty":"есть","categoryId":0,"priority":0},{"property":"Поддержка 3D","subProperty":"нет","categoryId":0,"priority":0},{"property":"Поддержка HDTV","subProperty":"да","categoryId":0,"priority":0},{"property":"Тип звуковой системы","subProperty":"стереозвук; Dolby Audio , DTS; Dolby Digital","categoryId":0,"priority":0},{"property":"Тюнер DVB-T2","subProperty":"да","categoryId":0,"priority":0},{"property":"Цифровой ТВ-тюнер","subProperty":"да","categoryId":0,"priority":0},{"property":"Комплектация","subProperty":"пульт управления; батарейка - 2 шт.; подставка - 2 шт.; комплект запасных винтов - 4 шт.; документация; телевизор; гарантийный талон","categoryId":0,"priority":0},{"property":"Страна производитель","subProperty":"Россия","categoryId":0,"priority":0}],"commentsCount":645,"sizeTypeId":3256,"technologies":[],"nonRefundable":true,"brandCod":19467,"subjectId":2819,"subjectRootId":6260,"brandRating":0,"sizeTableLastChangedDate":"\/Date(-62135596800000-0000)\/","regionIds":[31,33],"kindName":"","kindId":0,"hasCertificate":true,"groupedAddedOptions":[{"categoryId":7,"categoryName":"Общие характеристики","categoryPriority":95,"addedOptions":[{"property":"Версия операционной системы","subProperty":"Android TV","categoryId":7,"priority":0},{"property":"Модель","subProperty":"L43M5-5ARU","categoryId":7,"priority":0},{"property":"Гарантийный срок","subProperty":"1год","categoryId":7,"priority":0}]},{"categoryId":1,"categoryName":"Экран","categoryPriority":90,"addedOptions":[{"property":"Разрешение экрана","subProperty":"3840x2160","categoryId":1,"priority":0},{"property":"Угол обзора","subProperty":"178 градусов","categoryId":1,"priority":0},{"property":"Частота обновления","subProperty":"60 Гц","categoryId":1,"priority":0},{"property":"Диагональ","subProperty":"43\"","categoryId":1,"priority":0},{"property":"Разрешение HD","subProperty":"4K HDR","categoryId":1,"priority":0},{"property":"Формат экрана","subProperty":"16:9","categoryId":1,"priority":0},{"property":"Яркость","subProperty":"220 кд/кв.м","categoryId":1,"priority":0},{"property":"Контрастность","subProperty":"1200:1","categoryId":1,"priority":0}]},{"categoryId":6,"categoryName":"Другие функции","categoryPriority":85,"addedOptions":[{"property":"Цифровой тюнер","subProperty":"DVB-C; DVB-T; DVB-T2","categoryId":6,"priority":0},{"property":"Коммуникации и мультимедиа","subProperty":"Bluetooth; CI+; LAN; Smart TV; Web Браузер; Wi-Fi","categoryId":6,"priority":0}]},{"categoryId":21,"categoryName":"Акустическая система","categoryPriority":80,"addedOptions":[{"property":"Количество встроенных динамиков","subProperty":"2 шт.","categoryId":21,"priority":0},{"property":"Мощность акустики","subProperty":"16 Вт","categoryId":21,"priority":0}]},{"categoryId":15,"categoryName":"Интерфейсы и разъемы","categoryPriority":75,"addedOptions":[{"property":"Интерфейс","subProperty":"Bluetooth; Ethernet; HDMI; RJ-45; USB; Wi-Fi","categoryId":15,"priority":0},{"property":"Количество портов HDMI","subProperty":"3 шт.","categoryId":15,"priority":0},{"property":"Дополнительные разъемы","subProperty":"AV; CI+; DVB CAM; HDMI; Jack 3,5 мм; LAN; RJ-45","categoryId":15,"priority":0}]},{"categoryId":4,"categoryName":"Связь","categoryPriority":0,"addedOptions":[{"property":"Беспроводные интерфейсы","subProperty":"Bluetooth; Wi-Fi 802.11 b/g/n","categoryId":4,"priority":0}]},{"categoryId":0,"categoryName":"Дополнительная информация","categoryPriority":-1,"addedOptions":[{"property":"Потребляемая мощность","subProperty":"75 Вт","categoryId":0,"priority":0},{"property":"Вес с упаковкой (кг)","subProperty":"9 кг","categoryId":0,"priority":0},{"property":"Вес без упаковки (кг)","subProperty":"7.26 кг","categoryId":0,"priority":0},{"property":"Высота предмета","subProperty":"21.46 см","categoryId":0,"priority":0},{"property":"Глубина предмета","subProperty":"61.3 см","categoryId":0,"priority":0},{"property":"Ширина предмета","subProperty":"96.33 см","categoryId":0,"priority":0},{"property":"Ширина упаковки","subProperty":"120 см","categoryId":0,"priority":0},{"property":"Высота упаковки","subProperty":"38 см","categoryId":0,"priority":0},{"property":"Глубина упаковки","subProperty":"80 см","categoryId":0,"priority":0},{"property":"Доп. опции телевизора","subProperty":"защита от детей; телетекст; HDMI ARC; HDMI CEC","categoryId":0,"priority":0},{"property":"Размер VESA","subProperty":"300x300","categoryId":0,"priority":0},{"property":"Возможность крепления на стену","subProperty":"да","categoryId":0,"priority":0},{"property":"Skype камера","subProperty":"нет","categoryId":0,"priority":0},{"property":"Встроенный DVD","subProperty":"нет","categoryId":0,"priority":0},{"property":"Защита от детей","subProperty":"есть","categoryId":0,"priority":0},{"property":"Поддержка 3D","subProperty":"нет","categoryId":0,"priority":0},{"property":"Поддержка HDTV","subProperty":"да","categoryId":0,"priority":0},{"property":"Тип звуковой системы","subProperty":"стереозвук; Dolby Audio , DTS; Dolby Digital","categoryId":0,"priority":0},{"property":"Тюнер DVB-T2","subProperty":"да","categoryId":0,"priority":0},{"property":"Цифровой ТВ-тюнер","subProperty":"да","categoryId":0,"priority":0},{"property":"Комплектация","subProperty":"пульт управления; батарейка - 2 шт.; подставка - 2 шт.; комплект запасных винтов - 4 шт.; документация; телевизор; гарантийный талон","categoryId":0,"priority":0},{"property":"Страна производитель","subProperty":"Россия","categoryId":0,"priority":0}]}],"kit":"пульт управления, батарейка - 2 шт., подставка - 2 шт., комплект запасных винтов - 4 шт., документация, телевизор, гарантийный талон","isDigital":false,"rawProduct":{"mark":4,"commentsCount":645,"isNew":false,"goodsName":"Телевизор Mi TV 4S, 43\", UHD, Smart TV, Wi-Fi, DVB-T2","brandName":"Xiaomi","link":8198421,"sizeTypeId":3256,"regionIds":[31,33],"colors":[10842147],"oversized":false,"showSalePanel":false,"brandId":29467,"prepayOnly":false,"adult":false,"isCargo":false,"supplierName":"ВАЙЛДБЕРРИЗ ООО","orderQnt":11723,"countryId":156,"factoryId":643,"kit":"пульт управления, батарейка - 2 шт., подставка - 2 шт., комплект запасных винтов - 4 шт., документация, телевизор, гарантийный талон","hasBrandCertificate":true,"ao":[{"aoId":4346,"extId":96767,"factor":0},{"aoId":4381,"extId":211533,"factor":0},{"aoId":4972,"extId":31878,"factor":0},{"aoId":5023,"extId":211640,"factor":0},{"aoId":9623,"extId":17795,"factor":0},{"aoId":10466,"extId":18635,"factor":0},{"aoId":10466,"extId":116449,"factor":0},{"aoId":13894,"extId":22247,"factor":0},{"aoId":13894,"extId":81052,"factor":0},{"aoId":13894,"extId":100264,"factor":0},{"aoId":13894,"extId":119170,"factor":0},{"aoId":13894,"extId":154335,"factor":0},{"aoId":13894,"extId":418052,"factor":0},{"aoId":14995,"val":75,"siId":19,"factor":0},{"aoId":63269,"extId":70205,"factor":0},{"aoId":65229,"extId":71998,"factor":0},{"aoId":74989,"val":178,"siId":59,"factor":0},{"aoId":77752,"extId":83891,"factor":0},{"aoId":88953,"val":900,"siId":21,"factor":0},{"aoId":89064,"val":72600,"siId":21,"factor":2},{"aoId":90630,"val":214600,"siId":1,"factor":2},{"aoId":90652,"val":61300,"siId":1,"factor":1},{"aoId":90673,"val":963300,"siId":1,"factor":2},{"aoId":90745,"val":12000,"siId":1,"factor":0},{"aoId":90846,"val":3800,"siId":1,"factor":0},{"aoId":90849,"val":8000,"siId":1,"factor":0},{"aoId":92740,"extId":96829,"factor":0},{"aoId":92867,"extId":211534,"factor":0},{"aoId":92882,"extId":96917,"factor":0},{"aoId":92882,"extId":96918,"factor":0},{"aoId":92882,"extId":96919,"factor":0},{"aoId":92890,"extId":96928,"factor":0},{"aoId":92921,"val":220,"siId":107,"factor":0},{"aoId":92922,"extId":96963,"factor":0},{"aoId":122500,"extId":122537,"factor":0},{"aoId":122500,"extId":122538,"factor":0},{"aoId":122500,"extId":122539,"factor":0},{"aoId":122500,"extId":122553,"factor":0},{"aoId":122500,"extId":122583,"factor":0},{"aoId":122500,"extId":179206,"factor":0},{"aoId":122501,"val":2,"siId":2,"factor":0},{"aoId":122502,"val":16,"siId":19,"factor":0},{"aoId":122505,"extId":122549,"factor":0},{"aoId":122505,"extId":122554,"factor":0},{"aoId":122505,"extId":122555,"factor":0},{"aoId":122505,"extId":150415,"factor":0},{"aoId":122505,"extId":154992,"factor":0},{"aoId":122505,"extId":157694,"factor":0},{"aoId":122505,"extId":249894,"factor":0},{"aoId":122506,"extId":122540,"factor":0},{"aoId":122506,"extId":122541,"factor":0},{"aoId":122506,"extId":122891,"factor":0},{"aoId":122506,"extId":222865,"factor":0},{"aoId":122507,"extId":122893,"factor":0},{"aoId":122508,"extId":122546,"factor":0},{"aoId":354811,"extId":367848,"factor":0},{"aoId":354878,"extId":372100,"factor":0},{"aoId":354924,"extId":368947,"factor":0},{"aoId":355076,"extId":370101,"factor":0},{"aoId":355079,"extId":370104,"factor":0},{"aoId":355241,"extId":372102,"factor":0},{"aoId":355241,"extId":372103,"factor":0},{"aoId":355241,"extId":407756,"factor":0},{"aoId":355276,"extId":370214,"factor":0},{"aoId":355309,"extId":370040,"factor":0}],"complectIds":[322,782,962,3131,3850,4035,7510],"descriptionId":3730996,"alt":"Телевизор Mi TV 4S, 43\", UHD, Smart TV, Wi-Fi, DVB-T2 Xiaomi","cod1S":10842147,"sale":17,"colorName":"серебристый","video":true,"has3DView":false,"digitalGood":false,"allowSales":true,"allowCoupon":true,"promos":[65431,66080,66925,76394,79972,84211,90498,91592,92742,93897,96692,98660,103394,106351,106622],"subjectId":2819,"priceByChrt":{},"noReturn":true,"stores":[507,116433,120762],"color":[12632256]},"adult":false,"isCargo":false,"extIds":[96767,211533,31878,211640,17795,18635,116449,22247,81052,100264,119170,154335,418052,70205,71998,83891,96829,211534,96917,96918,96919,96928,96963,122537,122538,122539,122553,122583,179206,122549,122554,122555,150415,154992,157694,249894,122540,122541,122891,222865,122893,122546,367848,372100,368947,370101,370104,372102,372103,407756,370214,370040],"productDiscountRange":"17%","isElectronics":false,"isHideColor":false,"isVideo":false,"isActivationKey":false,"isInsurancePolicy":false,"canFit":false,"disableShowAdvantages":false},"selectedNomenclature":{"isSoldOut":false,"cod1S":10842147,"ordersCount":11700,"qualityRate":-1,"artikul":"10842147","minPriceForDcn":{"item1":22990,"item2":27699,"item3":17,"item4":false},"priceDetails":{"basicSale":17,"basicPrice":22990},"addToSellerEnable":false,"addToBasketEnable":true,"addToPonedEnable":true,"addToWaitingListEnable":false,"addToPreorderEnable":false,"allSizesSoldOut":false,"hasVideo":true,"sizes":{"34763855":{"addToSellerEnable":false,"addToBasketEnable":true,"addToPonedEnable":true,"addToWaitingListEnable":false,"addToPreorderEnable":false,"id":1,"sizeName":"0","dimensions":[],"characteristicId":34763855,"priceWithSale":22990,"price":27699,"quantity":1,"isSoldOut":false,"lowQuantity":false,"sale":17,"creditEnabled":true,"storeIds":[507,116433,120762],"hasPreorder":false,"sellerEnabled":false}},"kit":[],"relatedGoodsIds":[],"hasCreditSizes":true,"showSizeType":false,"rusName":"серебристый","picsCount":8,"has3D":false,"minOrderAmount":1,"hasSizesOnSeller":false,"hasSizesOnPreorder":false,"regionIds":[31,33],"enabledForRegion":true,"isDigital":false,"imageHelper":[{"preview":"//images.wbstatic.net/c516x688/new/10840000/10842147-1.jpg","zoom":"//images.wbstatic.net/big/new/10840000/10842147-1.jpg"},{"preview":"//images.wbstatic.net/c516x688/new/10840000/10842147-2.jpg","zoom":"//images.wbstatic.net/big/new/10840000/10842147-2.jpg"},{"preview":"//images.wbstatic.net/c516x688/new/10840000/10842147-3.jpg","zoom":"//images.wbstatic.net/big/new/10840000/10842147-3.jpg"},{"preview":"//images.wbstatic.net/c516x688/new/10840000/10842147-4.jpg","zoom":"//images.wbstatic.net/big/new/10840000/10842147-4.jpg"},{"preview":"//images.wbstatic.net/c516x688/new/10840000/10842147-5.jpg","zoom":"//images.wbstatic.net/big/new/10840000/10842147-5.jpg"},{"preview":"//images.wbstatic.net/c516x688/new/10840000/10842147-6.jpg","zoom":"//images.wbstatic.net/big/new/10840000/10842147-6.jpg"},{"preview":"//images.wbstatic.net/c516x688/new/10840000/10842147-7.jpg","zoom":"//images.wbstatic.net/big/new/10840000/10842147-7.jpg"},{"preview":"//images.wbstatic.net/c516x688/new/10840000/10842147-8.jpg","zoom":"//images.wbstatic.net/big/new/10840000/10842147-8.jpg"}],"urlForReccomendations":"/recommendations/catalog?type=visuallysimilar&forproduct=10842147","isDataLoaded":true},"selectedSize":{"addToSellerEnable":false,"addToBasketEnable":true,"addToPonedEnable":true,"addToWaitingListEnable":false,"addToPreorderEnable":false,"id":1,"sizeName":"0","dimensions":[],"characteristicId":34763855,"priceWithSale":22990,"price":27699,"quantity":1,"isSoldOut":false,"lowQuantity":false,"sale":17,"creditEnabled":true,"storeIds":[507,116433,120762],"hasPreorder":false,"sellerEnabled":false},"sizeTableLastChangedDate":"\/Date(-62135596800000-0000)\/","showSizeTable":false,"haveSize":false,"isDeleted":false,"isNotAvailable":false,"anySizeSoldOut":false,"hasVideo":true,"has3Dview":false,"popupMode":false,"catalogLink":"/brands/xiaomi","googleTagParams":"{\n  \"PageType\": \"product\",\n  \"Ptype\": [\n    \"Телевизор Mi TV 4S, 43\\\", UHD, Smart TV, Wi-Fi, DVB-T2\"\n  ],\n  \"Pbrand\": \"Xiaomi\",\n  \"ProdID\": [\n    10842147\n  ],\n  \"Value\": [\n    \"22990\"\n  ],\n  \"Discount\": \"17%\",\n  \"Delivery\": \"Бесплатная доставка\",\n  \"Psize\": []\n}","canChooseCredit":true,"showTones":false,"metaTags":{"10842147":{"title":"Телевизор Mi TV 4S, 43\", UHD, Smart TV, Wi-Fi, DVB-T2 Xiaomi 10842147 купить %FORPRICE% в интернет-магазине Wildberries","description":"Телевизор Mi TV 4S, 43\", UHD, Smart TV, Wi-Fi, DVB-T2 Xiaomi 10842147 в интернет-магазине Wildberries. Бесплатная доставка и постоянные скидки!"}},"nomenclatures":{"10842147":{"isSoldOut":false,"cod1S":10842147,"ordersCount":11700,"qualityRate":-1,"artikul":"10842147","minPriceForDcn":{"item1":22990,"item2":27699,"item3":17,"item4":false},"priceDetails":{"basicSale":17,"basicPrice":22990},"addToSellerEnable":false,"addToBasketEnable":true,"addToPonedEnable":true,"addToWaitingListEnable":false,"addToPreorderEnable":false,"allSizesSoldOut":false,"hasVideo":true,"sizes":{"34763855":{"addToSellerEnable":false,"addToBasketEnable":true,"addToPonedEnable":true,"addToWaitingListEnable":false,"addToPreorderEnable":false,"id":1,"sizeName":"0","dimensions":[],"characteristicId":34763855,"priceWithSale":22990,"price":27699,"quantity":1,"isSoldOut":false,"lowQuantity":false,"sale":17,"creditEnabled":true,"storeIds":[507,116433,120762],"hasPreorder":false,"sellerEnabled":false}},"kit":[],"relatedGoodsIds":[],"hasCreditSizes":true,"showSizeType":false,"rusName":"серебристый","picsCount":8,"has3D":false,"minOrderAmount":1,"hasSizesOnSeller":false,"hasSizesOnPreorder":false,"regionIds":[31,33],"enabledForRegion":true,"isDigital":false,"imageHelper":[{"preview":"//images.wbstatic.net/c516x688/new/10840000/10842147-1.jpg","zoom":"//images.wbstatic.net/big/new/10840000/10842147-1.jpg"},{"preview":"//images.wbstatic.net/c516x688/new/10840000/10842147-2.jpg","zoom":"//images.wbstatic.net/big/new/10840000/10842147-2.jpg"},{"preview":"//images.wbstatic.net/c516x688/new/10840000/10842147-3.jpg","zoom":"//images.wbstatic.net/big/new/10840000/10842147-3.jpg"},{"preview":"//images.wbstatic.net/c516x688/new/10840000/10842147-4.jpg","zoom":"//images.wbstatic.net/big/new/10840000/10842147-4.jpg"},{"preview":"//images.wbstatic.net/c516x688/new/10840000/10842147-5.jpg","zoom":"//images.wbstatic.net/big/new/10840000/10842147-5.jpg"},{"preview":"//images.wbstatic.net/c516x688/new/10840000/10842147-6.jpg","zoom":"//images.wbstatic.net/big/new/10840000/10842147-6.jpg"},{"preview":"//images.wbstatic.net/c516x688/new/10840000/10842147-7.jpg","zoom":"//images.wbstatic.net/big/new/10840000/10842147-7.jpg"},{"preview":"//images.wbstatic.net/c516x688/new/10840000/10842147-8.jpg","zoom":"//images.wbstatic.net/big/new/10840000/10842147-8.jpg"}],"urlForReccomendations":"/recommendations/catalog?type=visuallysimilar&forproduct=10842147","isDataLoaded":true}},"properNomenclaturesOrder":[10842147],"showSimilar":true,"farDeliveryEnable":false,"enabledForRegion":true,"questionsCount":0,"feedbacksCount":645,"openGraphDescription":"Телевизор LED Xiaomi Mi TV 4S 43 поддерживает встроенные тюнеры DVB-T, DVB-T2, DVB-C, что позволяет не подключать внешнюю приставку, чтобы смотреть цифровые телеканалы. Поддержка Smart TV, а также модуль Wi-Fi обеспечивают комфортное пользование цифровым контентом из сети. Вам будут доступны любые сведения в любом виде. Телевизор оборудован тремя разъемами HDMI и двумя разъемами USB, к которым происходит подключение внешних устройств и накопителей памяти. Xiaomi Mi TV 4S 43 поддерживает воспроизведение реалистичного изображения в разрешении 3840x2160, обладающего высокой четкостью. Картинка соответствует формату 4K, благодаря чему вы сможете погрузиться в происходящее на экране. Углы обзора 178 градусов обеспечивают получение комфортного изображения вне зависимости от ракурса просмотра. Прибор можно зафиксировать на стене, ведь он предусматривает поддержку стандарта крепления VESA 300x300.","brandLogoUrl":"//images.wbstatic.net/brands/small/new/29467.jpg","brandUrl":"/brands/xiaomi","isDobroBrand":false,"imageUploaderSettings":{"maxItemsCount":5,"useCropper":true,"minWidth":337,"minHeight":450,"messages":{"wrongFileSize":"Размер файла не должен превышать {0} Mb.","wrongFileExtension":"Поддерживаются только следующие расширения файлов «{0}»","filesLimitReached":"Вы можете загрузить не более {0} изображений","wrongImageResolution":"Разрешение изображения должно быть не менее {0}px по ширине и {1}px по высоте"},"uploadLimit":0,"supportedExtensions":["jpg","gif","jpeg","png","bmp"]},"urlHelper":{"toBasket":"/product/addtobasket"},"searchTags":{"tagsQuery":"C этим товаром искали","drawType":1,"tagsViewModels":[{"href":"/catalog/0/search.aspx?search=%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d1%80+mi&targeturl=ST&xsearch=true","text":"телевизор mi","type":1},{"href":"/catalog/0/search.aspx?search=%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d1%80+xiaomi&targeturl=ST&xsearch=true","text":"телевизор xiaomi","type":1},{"href":"/catalog/0/search.aspx?search=xiaomi&targeturl=ST&xsearch=true","text":"xiaomi","type":1},{"href":"/catalog/0/search.aspx?search=mi+tv&targeturl=ST&xsearch=true","text":"mi tv","type":1},{"href":"/catalog/0/search.aspx?search=%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d1%80+smart+tv+43&targeturl=ST&xsearch=true","text":"телевизор smart tv 43","type":1},{"href":"/catalog/0/search.aspx?search=%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%88%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b9%d0%bd+%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f+%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0&targeturl=ST&xsearch=true","text":"кронштейн для телевизора","type":1},{"href":"/catalog/0/search.aspx?search=%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d1%80+smart+tv&targeturl=ST&xsearch=true","text":"телевизор smart tv","type":1},{"href":"/catalog/0/search.aspx?search=xiaomi+tv&targeturl=ST&xsearch=true","text":"xiaomi tv","type":1},{"href":"/catalog/0/search.aspx?search=%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d1%80+%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c+55&targeturl=ST&xsearch=true","text":"телевизор диагональ 55","type":1},{"href":"/catalog/0/search.aspx?search=%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d1%80&targeturl=ST&xsearch=true","text":"телевизор","type":1}]},"targetInfo":{"targetUrl":"GP","targetCode":0,"sort":0,"targetUrlExtended":"GP||||"},"sitePath":[{"id":4830,"name":"Электроника","sort":0,"pageUrl":"/catalog/elektronika","filterMap":0,"childGenerator":0,"topMenuRenderer":0,"leftMenuRenderer":0,"landingPage":true},{"id":9834,"parentId":4830,"name":"ТВ, Аудио, Фото, Видео техника","sort":0,"pageUrl":"/catalog/elektronika/tv-audio-foto-video-tehnika","filterMap":0,"childGenerator":0,"topMenuRenderer":0,"leftMenuRenderer":0,"landingPage":false},{"id":9924,"parentId":9834,"name":"Телевизоры","sort":0,"pageUrl":"/catalog/elektronika/tv-audio-foto-video-tehnika/televizory/televizory","filterMap":0,"childGenerator":0,"topMenuRenderer":0,"leftMenuRenderer":0,"landingPage":false},{"id":0,"name":"Xiaomi","sort":0,"pageUrl":"/brands/xiaomi","filterMap":0,"childGenerator":0,"topMenuRenderer":0,"leftMenuRenderer":0,"landingPage":false}]},
```

Например получить "supplierName":"ВАЙЛДБЕРРИЗ ООО". Пробовал так:

```
result = search(r'"supplierName":\s\b\w+\b(?![^<]*>)\s\b\w+\b(?![^<]*>)', js_script[20])
```

Но если supplierName содержит больше, чем 2 слова, то в result = None

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вытащил регуляркой и распарсил как `json`

Пример:

```
import json
import re

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


session = requests.Session()
session.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:84.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/84.0'

links_product = ['https://www.wildberries.ru/catalog/10842147/detail.aspx?targetUrl=GP']
for url in links_product:
    response = session.get(url, timeout=10)
    if response.status_code != 200:
        continue

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    js_scripts = soup.find_all('script')
    js_script = str(js_scripts[20])

    m = re.search('ssrModel: (.+),', js_script)
    data = json.loads(m.group(1))
    print(data['suppliersInfo']['10842147'])
    # {'cod1S': 10842147, 'supplierName': 'ВАЙЛДБЕРРИЗ ООО', 'ogrn': '1067746062449'}
```